# Reuse attributes on many elements in XSD

Tags: xsd, attributes

Is there a way in XML Schema to define/name a set of attributes that can be reused on many element definitions without cutting/pasting the whole attribute definition into each element definition?

For example, if I want three attributes on 20 different elements in my xsd, can I name these as a group somehow once and reference them without having to have the same full definition repeated as part of all 20 elements?

```
<xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="page" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="alphabet" type="xs:string"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is '[xs:attributeGroup](http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/databinding/examples/6/09/AttributeGroup/)' for this purpose.